# Using excel for tracking project timelines

Tags: microsoft-excel, project-management

I am trying to put together a doc (preferably excel sheet) that I can use to track software projects with my team mates. Here's what I want. I want a way so I can lay out all the weeks in one quarter horizontally. And then for each week I want to have 2 things vertically :

1. What project is being worked on?
2. Who' working on it?

This way, I can have a nice weekly visualization of what are all the projects being worked on and who's working on them and I can then parallelize resources (designs/engineering) so that things move along smoothly. My excel foo is not that great but I have feeling that there's definitely a way to do this in excel (or otherwise)

Comment: What you describe sounds like a date function to generate week labels plus a couple of row labels.  Everything else would be data you enter.  Can you be more specific about what your problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are doing [Scrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28software_development%29). Here are a few [templates](https://www.mitchlacey.com/resources/sprint-excel-templates). One for 14 day and one for 30 day.

We're using [iceSrum](https://www.icescrum.com/), it's an OpenSource project, if you are thinking of going into that direction.